# <span> and <ul> vertical alignment

Tags: html, css, css-float, vertical-alignment

I have a `<span>` element followed by a horizontal `<ul>` element. Why is there a left and bottom margin on the `<ul`>? How can I remove this space?

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/bpy8w8uy/)

HTML

```
<span>AAAAA</span>
<ul>
    <li>BBBBB</li>
    <li>CCCC</li>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

span {
  background-color: #f00;
}

ul {
  background-color: #0f0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

Comment: are you trying to display AAAA BBBB CCCC in one line, without any space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this out!

Added `inline-block` to the span and `vertical-align` too.
The span has a visual margin / space because it is not `inline-block` and the `ul` next to it but is `inline-block`

Is this what you expected? Please let me know your feedback on this. Thanks!

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
span {
  background-color: #f00;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
ul {
  background-color: #0f0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<span>AAAAA</span>
<ul>
  <li>BBBBB</li>
  <li>CCCC</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried different combinations with `display` but never worked. I think what I was really missing is `vertical-align: top;`. Stupid CSS... Thanks!

Comment: `Stupid CSS` is a lie. Stupid is always between the screen and the chair. This can be solved removing the defaults margin/padding of the `<li>` too, every browser have different values for this kind of things. Not guilty CSS, trust me.

Answer (score 0):

As the other users already stated, `display: inline-block;` should do the trick, but your fiddle seems like you already got that right. To find out where unexpected margins, borders or other css stuff come from, I rely on firebug (Firefox Plugin for web developers).

Comment: Firebug is old and slow down your browser. All browsers have right now its own developer tools, including firefox. At this moment, firefox have the best developer tools of all browsers, in design and in functionalities. Take a look, press `Shift+F2`

Answer (score 0):

while you are using display inline-block give font-size: 0; to the parent element.

Try this code...

```
 body {
  background-color: #000;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 0;
}

span {
  background-color: #f00;
  font-size: 14px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

ul {
  background-color: #0f0;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

ul > li {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 1em;
  font-size: 14px;
}
```